# In Netron model viewer, what does "runtime" mean?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, model-viewer

In [Netron model viewer](https://github.com/lutzroeder/netron), what does the "runtime" field means?

Is it the TensorFlow version that used to create this model?
[Screenshot of Netron model properties section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ko6E5.png)

Comment: For future questions, can someone clarify why this question got "-1"? I have searched for the answer online and couldn't find the answer..and it might help other people in understanding models when using Netron model viewer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by the author of this tool in his GitHub issue board:

> For TensorFlow Lite, it contains the min_runtime_version required to run the model.

Source: [Answer on GitHub](https://github.com/lutzroeder/netron/issues/753)